# Access isdenied to hosts file

Tags: vb.net, vbscript

When I run my program in Visual Studio it works perfectly without admin privileges. But when I run program using .exe file error occurred - Access to path `C:/Windows/System32/drivers/etc/host` I tried running it as Administrator, does not work at all!

Here's my code -

```
Dim file As System.IO.StreamWriter
file = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter("C:/Windows/System32/drivers/etc/hosts", True)
file.WriteLine("127.0.0.1 " + www.google.lk)
file.Close()
```

Comment: Hi Yohan, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Can I check something about your code - does it really use `&quot;` or does it actually have a normal ordinary double-quote `"` in those places?

Comment: Yup, only `"` @Vince Bowdren

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have any type of anti-spyware program installed? Some will prevent the hosts file from being modded. This vbscript works for me. Removes read only attribute, performs edit and reapplies read only attribute. Because this has some repeated code, it probably should be modded to have a function to be more "proper".

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Const ForReading =   1
Const ForWriting =   2
Const ForAppending = 8
Const ReadOnly =     1

strWinDir = WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%windir%")
HostsFile = strWinDir & "\System32\drivers\etc\hosts"

Set objFile = objFSO.GetFile(HostsFile)
If objFile.Attributes AND ReadOnly Then
  objFile.Attributes = objFile.Attributes XOR ReadOnly
End If

Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(HostsFile, ForAppending)
objFile.WriteLine(vbNewLine & "127.0.0.1 www.google.lk")
objFile.Close

Set objFile = objFSO.GetFile(HostsFile)
If Not objFile.Attributes AND ReadOnly Then
  objFile.Attributes = objFile.Attributes XOR ReadOnly
End If
```

Code to remove same string.

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Const ForReading =   1
Const ForWriting =   2
Const ForAppending = 8
Const ReadOnly =     1

strWinDir = WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%windir%")
HostsFile = strWinDir & "\System32\drivers\etc\hosts"

Set objFile = objFSO.GetFile(HostsFile)
If objFile.Attributes AND ReadOnly Then
  objFile.Attributes = objFile.Attributes XOR ReadOnly
End If

Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(HostsFile, ForReading)

Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
  strLine = objFile.ReadLine
    If InStr(strLine, "127.0.0.1 www.google.lk") = 0 Then
      strContents = strContents & strLine & vbCrLf
    End If
Loop
objFile.Close

Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(HostsFile, ForWriting)
objFile.Write strContents
objFile.Close

Set objFile = objFSO.GetFile(HostsFile)
If Not objFile.Attributes AND ReadOnly Then
  objFile.Attributes = objFile.Attributes XOR ReadOnly
End If
```

Comment: Pls help me, I don't know VB.NET well.. This is an assignment of me.. pls pls help @Randy Schuman

Comment: This is VBscript, not vb.net. Just save all this code into a file with a .vbs extension, then it can be called with a batch file or from some other program or installer using %windir%\system32\cscript.exe filename.vbs  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156587.aspx

Comment: Ohh yes I understand! Thank you very much it's works perfectly. By the way there another thing, how can I remove **"127.0.0.1 www.google.lk"** from hosts file using VB Script?? If it is possible I can unblock the site so. @Randy Schuman

Comment: okay I marked it! Can I prevent vbs file detecting as a malware by antivirus software? @Randy Schuman

Comment: thanx @Randy Schuman for helping me. You are a Genius!! thanx again

Answer (score 0):

As you can see only admins can write to it.

```
 C:\Windows\system32>icacls "C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts"

 C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(F)

                                       BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(F)

                                       BUILTIN\Users:(I)(RX)

                                       APPLICATION PACKAGE AUTHORITY\ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES:(I)(RX)

 Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files
```

Comment: Yup! I tried running as **Administrator** also change **requested execution level** from **"asInvoker" to "highestAvailable"** in **app.manifes**t file. But still getting _"Access is denied"_ error message. Is there any other way to edit _hosts_ file? or any way to get permission to access _hosts_? Pls help me... @Ndls